# Difference between adding the rounded and non rounded double value with date?

Tags: c#, datetime

What is the difference between adding the rounded number in a date and adding non rounded number in a date?

Does this make any difference during calculation?

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
// adding rounded number with date
date = date.AddDays(1);

//adding unrounded number with date         
date = date.AddDays(1.346);
```

Comment: Did you even try it?

Comment: Of course floating point representation make different result from plain integer. 1.346 means 1 day, 8 hours, 18 minutes, 14 seconds and 400 ticks (CMIIW).

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN for DateTime.AddDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> **Remarks:**
>
> The fractional part of valueis the fractional part of a day. For
> example, 4.5 is equivalent to 4 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds,
> 0 milliseconds, and 0 ticks.
>
> The value parameter is rounded to the nearest millisecond.